# Debugging a crash that does not happen inside a debugger

Tags: c++, debugging, stl, crash

I split a monolithic piece of code into dynamically loaded library and `main()` that calls it. I use no other library than stdc++, nor are there any classes, just a templated struct that has no member functions. I am not allocating any memory explicitly nor deleting or freeing anything in the code. I do use erase objects from a `list<T>`.

After the switch to  library + main I am getting intermittent crashes.

`*** glibc detected *** : free(): invalid pointer:`

From the backtrace it seems a list itertor is involved, but the name mangled symbols make it hard to be sure.

However it does not crash inside gdb, nor does valgrind detect any memory corruption or leaks.

I have not build shared libraries before. This is what I am using

`g++ -fPIC -shared library_src.cpp -o libblaH.so`

`g++ main.cpp -lblaH`

The entirety of the library is in a single source file, the library function is wrapped in an  `extern "C"` block to make it accessible to c users, but right now i am compiling main() with g++ as a c++ code.

Now when I add optimization options, `-O2` (in particular) I start getting the crashes.

I have tried `electricfence` it says the invalid pointer was not allocated by malloc.

I would appreciate suggestions on how to hunt the bug down. My feeling is that I am invalidation a list iterator somewhere, but how I am not sure. I thought they cant be invalidated, except for deleted entries.

Comment: if you put all code into one monolithic compilation unit, the error does not show?

Comment: @Walter Yes that is correct. Well, it hasnt in any of the 10~15 number of times I have run it. But even the library version does not crash always, abut once ievery 5 times when I have -O2 in the flags, and no crashes if no optimization flags are set.

Comment: If debugger does not work, you can use `printf` to trace the bug, without attaching a debugger, so you can see which object is using the `free` function.

Comment: Try `c++filt` to demangle the names in the stacktrace, maybe that helps you.

Comment: I know this type of error (had it myself many times) and only remember that the error message is not very helpful really. But you most likely have written into memory where you shouldn't. I usually use the printing-out approach instead of debugging (because things are not always the same in the debugger, as you've noticed, but print-out statements may also change the code -- the compiler can re-order things and suddenly all works)

Comment: You should verify if you're not writing into read-only memory (`.data` of the program, etc...)

Comment: @Synxis evnu Walter Thanks for all of your suggestions. I will do a careful pass and see whats going on, and yes I usually prefer printf based debugging over debuggers. Now I have a reason to justify my choice !

Comment: Compile with `-Wall -Wextra` flags to enable compiler warnings, it may report something interesting. Always a good practice anyway.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Indeed. I use -Wall, might as well throw in -Wextra. What really helped this time was looking at the core dump.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason this scream uninitialized variable to me. Many years ago when I charge companies by the hour to help debug crash just like this, and half the time, the problem was uninitialized variables.

The approach I would use is:

1. Systematically initialize ALL variables, and initialize them ALL at declaration. Absolutely no exceptions.
2. Look for invalidated iterators. i.e. iterator pointing to erased object is invalidated and should not be used.
3. Look for variable hijacking. i.e. variables with the same name worked fine in same translation unit but doesn't work in separate translation units.
4. Look for unsafe function calls such as sprintf, where format string doesn't match parameters.
5. Use #pragma to selectively disable optimization in part of the code to narrow down problem area. Kind of like binary search; disable 1st half, still crash, problem in 2nd half, disable 1st half and 1/2 of 2nd half...

I'm assuming no multiple threads are involved. When threads are involved, a lot more things could go wrong. When I was hired at customer site, I always have them initialize all variables first before I even launch any debugger. 50% of the time I can go home after step 1.